# Using Mockito's anyString() in a rule doesn't work with "normal" values in other rules

Tags: mockito

I have this issue where I want my mock to return specific values in some specific cases and another value in any other case, represented by `anyString()` in the code below.

```
@Test
public void testMockitoWithAny() {
    // Mock the object
    List<String> list = mock(List.class);

    // populate the mock with the rules
    when(list.add("abc")).thenReturn(false);      // first rule
    when(list.add(anyString())).thenReturn(true); // default rule

    // Verify the rules.
    assertTrue(list.add("xyz"));                  // Ok
    assertFalse(list.add("abc"));                 // AssertionError.
}
```

How to make such a statement with Mockito?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer. I only need to switch the rules to have the default one set up first.

```
@Test
public void testMockitoWithAny() {
    // Mock the object
    List<String> list = mock(List.class);

    // populate the mock with the rules
    when(list.add(anyString())).thenReturn(true); // default rule
    when(list.add("abc")).thenReturn(false);      // first rule

    // Verify the rules.
    assertTrue(list.add("xyz"));                  // Ok
    assertFalse(list.add("abc"));                 // Ok
}
```

Comment: In Mockito, the _last-defined matching rule wins_. This allows general setup in `setUp` and `@Before` methods with overrides in particular `@Test`s, but requires that general rules come before (i.e. above) specific cases.

Answer (score 0):

You need a matcher which matches any String except "abc":

```
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;
...

when(list.add(argThat(not(equalTo("abc"))))).thenReturn(true); // default rule
```

Comment: Why do I keep making SSCCE? Half of my simplified questions get answers not fitting to my actual case. In this actual case, I have a full list of strings, which provide several different (mockito's) answers. Do I really have to repeat all those in the, I suppose, `argThat(not(in(Arrays.asList("abc","def","ghi"))))`? Isn't there anything more clever included in Mockito?

Comment: I'm not aware of any such thing. But this looks like a test doing too many things. Couldn't you split it in simpler tests?

Comment: Well, sometimes I have to simulate several very specific things in a 200 lines method and I don't have time to refactor, making your suggestion unfortunately unuseful in my case. Thanks anyways! :)